# How to responsive image in ionic from different screen size?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app, in that I need to add a four images in my home page in two row and each row has two images. The images size is 296*296.
I have tried the below code,

**index.html**

```
<ion-nav-view class="container" >
</ion-nav-view>
```

**Home.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="HOME">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-6 " id="img1">
         <img src="img/hard.png" class="img-responsive " id="img1" > 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" id="img1">
         <img src="img/soft.png" class="img-responsive " id="img1"> 
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-6 " id="img1">
         <img src="img/welcome.png" class="img-responsive " id="img1" > 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" id="img1">
         <img src="img/title.png" class="img-responsive " id="img1"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

**CSS**

```
#img1{
    width: 100%;
height: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ids for div and img are same i.e img1. Change the id and then try. And make width and height important may be some other css overwrites it. Tell me if this works or not.

```css
#img2{
 width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 " id="img1">
         <img src="img/hard.png" class="img-responsive " id="img2" > 
      </div>
```

Comment: I have change according but not working.Actually UI is responsive in browser responsive tag but when I run on android device then screen is not responsive.

Comment: Will you please provide some more explanation or your plunker or fiddle something.

Comment: This is my first application in ionic and I know only basic concept.what actually I am trying to do is I want four images below the header in two row and each row has two images but when I run the code on ionic run android the application is install but the screen is not responsive but the same screen is responsive when I run ionic run browser i.e. on browser.I am not getting what's the problem.

Comment: You may try media queries like for iphone 6 it is : @media(max-width:750px) and (max-height:1334px){-----css-------}

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue. This code might help to you 
HTML

```
    <div class="list card new-feeds wall-post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="item item-image img4">
                <img src="img/hard.png">
            </div>
            <div class="item item-image img4">
                <img src="img/soft.png">
            </div>
            <div class="item item-image img4">
                <img src="img/welcome.png">
            </div>
            <div class="item item-image img4">
                <img src="img/title.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wall-post .img4 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
}
.img4 > img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```